# Qt - Scrolling the visible area of the chart

Tags: c++, qt, charts, scroll

I'm beginner at Qt, and currently learning from Mastering Qt5 book and I got stuck. There is a piece of code

```
// Global variables
const int CHART_X_RANGE_COUNT = 50;
const int CHART_X_RANGE_MAX = CHART_X_RANGE_COUNT - 1;

void MemoryWidget::updateSeries()
{
  double memoryUsed = SysInfo::instance().memoryUsed(); // retrieve the latest memory percentage used
  mSeries->append(mPointPositionX++, memoryUsed);
  if (mSeries->count() > CHART_X_RANGE_COUNT)
  {
    QChart *chart = chartView().chart();
    chart->scroll(chart->plotArea().width() / CHART_X_RANGE_MAX, 0);
    mSeries->remove(0);
  }
}
```

I only don't understand the following piece of code

```
chart->scroll(chart->plotArea().width() / CHART_X_RANGE_MAX, 0);
```

If I want to scroll to the latest point on the X axis and nothing on Y, then why i have to do this:

```
chart->plotArea().width() / CHART_X_RANGE_MAX
```

and can't do just this:

```
chart->scroll(1, 0);
```

Comment: Because the units are not pixels but the same unit of the x-axes.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d if you think my post is more useful you can upvote and accept both.

Comment: @saeed I would upvote your post, but I only have 12 reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs `scroll` Scrolls the visible area of the chart by the distance specified by dx and dy.

and why `chart->scroll(chart->plotArea().width() / CHART_X_RANGE_MAX, 0);`

because `mSeries->append(mPointPositionX++, memoryUsed);` is called periodically and after a while a full window of xaxis will be filled and after each full window fills plot will scroll, if you use `chart->scroll(1, 0);` each time `updateSeries()` called you scroll window to next and always showing last point,

In general this plot wants to scroll per `CHART_X_RANGE_MAX`.